# Can cuda execution blocks be interrupted during execution?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am worried about a potential race condition in one of my cuda kernels.  I am working on an N-Body simulator for the Barnes Hunt Tree algorithm.  The purpose of this kernel is to compute the total mass, and centres of mass for each branch of the tree. I want to "iterate" in reverse order on the containers array because those allocated last are least likely to depend on other child containers, also the first containers in the array likely do depend on later containers.

I am using an atomic counter to track which blocks start first and the first block handles the first few container and so on.  What I am worried about is can the execution of a block be temporally suspended until other blocks finish or something like that?  This is an issue since say the first block starts and then yields for the others for whatever reason.  In this case if the others depend on computation performed by the first block they will loop indefinatly.

```
__global__ void compute_mass_centers_kernel()
{
    int blockNum = atomicAdd(&dev::block_number, 1);
    int cindex = dev::ncontainers - blockNum * blockDim.x - 1 - threadIdx.x;
    if(cindex < 0)
        return;

    Container& c = dev::containers[cindex];
    int missing_ptrs[8];
    int missing = 0;

    float total_mass = 0.0f;
    double3 com = {0}; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(c[i] > 1)
        {
            Object& o = objat(c[i]);
            total_mass += o.m;
            com.x += (double)o.p.x * o.m;
            com.y += (double)o.p.y * o.m;
            com.z += (double)o.p.z * o.m;
        }
        else if(c[i] < 1)
        {
            missing_ptrs[missing++] = c[i];
        }
    }

    while(missing)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < missing; i++)
        {
            Container& c2 = ctrat(missing_ptrs[i]);
            if(c2.total_mass >= 0.0f)
            {
                total_mass += c2.total_mass;
                com.x += (double)c2.center_of_mass.x * c2.total_mass;
                com.y += (double)c2.center_of_mass.y * c2.total_mass;
                com.z += (double)c2.center_of_mass.z * c2.total_mass;
                missing_ptrs[i--] = missing_ptrs[--missing];
            }
        }
    }

    c.center_of_mass.x = com.x / total_mass;
    c.center_of_mass.y = com.y / total_mass;
    c.center_of_mass.z = com.z / total_mass;
    c.total_mass = total_mass;
}

void compute_mass_centers()
{
    int threads, blocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&blocks, &threads, compute_mass_centers_kernel, 0, 0);
    cucheck();

    int ncontainers;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&ncontainers, dev::ncontainers, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cucheck();

    blocks = (ncontainers + (threads - 1)) / threads;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev::block_number, &ZERO, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cucheck();

    compute_mass_centers_kernel<<< blocks, threads >>>();
    cucheck();
}
```

Comment: I am really not 100% sure what it is you really want to know here because it seems connected to that code dump you included, but there is no guarantee of block scheduling, execution, or retirement order in the CUDA runtime model. Any code which relies on a predetermined execution order is really relying on undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like a CUDA inter-block synchronize. Nevertheless, people have done research on that, for example: [Shucai Xiao and Wu-chun Feng](http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00001087/01/TR_GPU_synchronization.pdf), *Inter-Block  GPU  Communication
via  Fast  Barrier  Synchronization*

In your case one could simply do either several kernel calls with each one block or if you are adventuresome a self-made (slow) blocking atomic operation in global memory to synchronize.

For your underlying problem the best solution might be to check your code with [cuda-memcheck](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/).

Comment: It's always worth pointing out that there is no way to have any sort of dependency between blocks while conforming to the CUDA programming model. The code may work now, but there's no guaretee it'll work tomorrow.

Comment: why did I get a down-vote? interesting, I think I made it very clear there is no such thing as an inter-block sync in CUDA in sentence one. Paragraph 2 is a debug possibility to start several kernels instead of one and paragraph 3 is the actual tool he is looking for but does not seem to know it exists.